# how to reduce the space

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

hi I am trying to implement a kendo donut .
As per image I did it but there are more space between status bar and donut .

My html code :-

```
    <style>
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: -214px;
        margin-left: -131px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style> 
<div id="brazil">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div class="overlay" style="display: none;"><div>No Requests For The Current Year</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js code :-

```
       function createChart(s, s) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/tgf.mvc/ss?siteId=" + s,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    title: {
                        text: ""
                    },
                    chartArea: {
                        position: "center"      
                    },
                    legend: {
                        labels: {
                            visible: true,
                            template: kendo.template("#: text # #: Math.floor(percentage*100) #%"),
                            position: "center",


                        },
                        position: "left"
                    },
                    dataSource: {
                        data: data123
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: "donut",
                        field: "value",
                        categoryField: "source",
                        explodeField: "explode",

                        labels: {
                            visible: true,
                            position: "center",
                            template: "#: value # Files"
                        }
                    }]
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: false,
                        template: "${ category } - ${ value }"
                    }
                });
```

things I tried
1.tried to reduce the weigh but still having the space .
anyone please help me on it ?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nudX7.png)

Comment: What is *weigh*  ? Do you mean `width` or `height` ? I think you should reduce the `width` of the container.

Comment: sorry width and i tried  offsetX: -50,
                        offsetY: -50 as well

Comment: when I  reduce the width  from right to left reducing .but the space remaining the same .

Comment: If you could do a dojo of it, it will be easier to help.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown https://dojo.telerik.com/uyuRuMom/3

Comment: this have the similar issue like mine. I refer the same

Comment: Yeah, idk how to solve that. Its all made in SVG, not html/css, do I don't think there is much options to redesign it.

Answer (score 0):

The space is dependent on the `width` of the container the chart is in at the time it is initialized.

You can set the `width` before the chart is initialized: [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uyuRuMom/8)

```html
<div id="chart" style="width:400px;"></div>
```

If you change the width after the chart is initialized, you then need to [redraw](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/redraw) the chart. This will repaint the chart on screen: [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uyuRuMom/9)

```js
$("#chart").width(400);
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
```